# ln(n) + 1 Approximation for Set Cover constructions

Tags: approximation

Set Cover Problem: Given a set $X$ and a collection of subsets $S_1, S_2, \ldots S_m \subseteq S$, we want to find the smallest cardinality of a set of $k$ elements $\{i_1, \ldots i_k \}$ such that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i = 1}^k S_{i_j} = X$.

Let $o$ be the size of optimal solution for the Set Cover problem. We know that there exists an approximation algorithm which yields solution $k$ such that $\frac{k}{o} \leq \ln(n) + 1$. As such, the approximation ratio is unbounded and can achieve large values for large $n$. Note that this algorithm is greedy and repeatedly chooses the set which covers the largest amount of elements that haven't been covered yet.

What is a methodical way to construct a set of size $n$ and all of the input subsets, such that increasing the size of $n$ monotonically increases the approximation ratio?

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2017/cmsc451-0101/Lects/lect09-set-cover.pdf